# What is the cardinality between Message and Exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to understand the cardinality between Messages and Exchanges. In the following route, by the time one message makes it to the final log how many Exchanges are created?

```
from("timer:one-second-timer")
  .bean(messageTransformer, "transformMessage")
  .to("log:logging-end-point");
```

Since a Message can hold only one "in" message, I imagine there will be one Message for each end-point the message hops on. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider an `Exchange` as being the envelope containing the `Message` + some meta-data (the `Properties`), allowing this message to be transported between endpoints.

The javadoc says:

> An Exchange is the message container holding the information during
> the entire routing of a Message received by a Consumer.

So, in your example, if the timer is fired 10 times, this will result in 10 distinct exchanges of one message.